# Javascript writing into a text area from button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wanting to write into a textarea from buttons clicked by users using Javascript *or jQuery*

Like so:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

    <button>Q</button>
    <button>W</button>
    <button>E</button>
    <button>R</button>
    <button>T</button>
    <button>Y</button>

    <br/><br/>  

    <textarea></textarea>

    </body>
</html>
```

So a user can click one of the "QWERTY" buttons here and it will be pasted into the box below. Is there a relatively simple way to do this? I've looked up some examples online, but they all go overboard for a novice like me.

It would also be great if we could write text to the `textarea` characters that aren't on the `button`

---

I can't seem to get this to work

```
    <html>
        <head>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

        <script>$('button').click(function(){        
    $('textarea').text($('textarea').text() + $(this).text());
    //$('input:text').val($('textarea').text() );
    $('input:text').val($('input:text').val() + ' ' + $(this).data('stuff'));
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<button data-stuff='stuff_Q'>Q</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_W'>W</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_E'>E</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_R'>R</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_T'>T</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_Y'>Y</button>
<br/><br/>  
<input type='text'/>
<br/><br/>  
<textarea></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JS

```
$('button').click(function(){        
    $('textarea').text($('textarea').text() + $(this).text());
    //$('input:text').val($('textarea').text() );
    $('input:text').val($('input:text').val() + ' ' + $(this).data('stuff'));
});
```

### HTML

```
<button data-stuff='stuff_Q'>Q</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_W'>W</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_E'>E</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_R'>R</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_T'>T</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_Y'>Y</button>
<br/><br/>  
<input type='text'/>
<br/><br/>  
<textarea></textarea>
```

Updated per OP needs additional appending values after all the button clicked.

Updated again per OP asking "write into the textbox a letter that is different from the button tag says". I would like to store some data for each button using data() to get it.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/ztz4Lf23/)

Comment: could we write into the textbox a letter that is different from the button tag says?

Comment: sorry I didn't mean `textbox.` I want to click on a button and have it paste something other than what the button says. For example, the button Q when pressed would paste F or something.

Comment: Updated. Hope it is you wants.

Comment: wait. in the textbox the new_stuff isn't adding, it's overwriting

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just append to the end of the textarea then use

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var letter = $(this).text();

    $('textarea')[0].value += letter;
});
```

---

Full demo

```js
$(function() {

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var letter = $(this).text();

    $('textarea')[0].value += letter;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Q</button>
<button>W</button>
<button>E</button>
<button>R</button>
<button>T</button>
<button>Y</button>

<br/>
<br/>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
     $('textarea').text( $(this).text() );
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8xhgc17p/)

---

If you want to take this example a bit futher, we can make it so the letters are appended to the textarea, rather than overwriting what was there previously:

```
var ta = $('textarea'); //cache selector for re-use (see note at bottom)
$('button').click(function(){
    ta.text( ta.text() + $(this).text() );
});
```

---

Now, let's add a button to erase the textarea. Here we assign an ID to one specific button and check for it:

```
var ta = $('textarea');
$('button').click(function(){
    if (this.id == "eraseit"){
        ta.text('');
    }else{
        ta.text( ta.text() + $(this).text() );
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/8xhgc17p/1/)

Notes:

1. In the 2nd and 3rd examples, we `cached` the selector (saved the reference into a variable) for speed.

Each time the code `$('textarea')` is hit, the DOM is searched for that selector. Caching the selector eliminates all but the initial search. Not at all important in this simple example, but very useful on a large project.

2. IDs and Classes are extremely important. They are used similarly by css and by javascript/jQuery, for identifying/selecting elements.

The same class name can be applied to multiple elements (e.g. several buttons can have the class), but no two elements are allowed to have the same ID.

---

In response to your question:

```
var ta = $('textarea');
$('button').click(function(){
    if (this.id == "eraseit"){
        ta.text('');
    }else{
        if ( $(this).hasClass('bob') )  {
            ta.text( ta.text() + ' bob' );
        }else if ( $(this).hasClass('x') )  {
            var ans = prompt('What is your name?');
            ta.text( ta.text() + ans );
        }else{
            ta.text( ta.text() + $(this).text() );
        }
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo #3](http://jsfiddle.net/8xhgc17p/2/)